# Does kernel have its own stack other than kernel thread stack?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, kernel, x86-64

In x86_64, Linux, does the kernel have its own stack, other than kernel threads' stacks?

And does it have something called kernel process like FreeBSD has?

Comment: What do you mean "kernel have its own stack other than kernel threads"?  Roughly speaking a set of kernel threads and uspace processes in system mode is a kernel. So what is your question about?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, kernel has a seperate stack for IRQ & per process/thread stack for handling system calls. I don't think there is any other stack needed. Kernel code is executed either in process context or interrupt context so there are seperate stacks for both.

Comment: By default interrupt code uses kernel thread stack, there is no separate stack for IRQs

Comment: Yes interrupt stack is in kernel space & common for all the processes

Comment: My understanding is that when 2 pages of RAM are given to the kernel stack for each process (through compile-time options), the kernel stack for the current process is also used for IRQs. When only 1 page of RAM is given to each kernel stack, a dedicated stack for IRQs is allocated *for each CPU*.

Comment: There are kernel threads, and they each have their own stack.